# Passing $scope variable in function wont change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this app that has different themes a user can pick from a navbar. At this point Im just trying to  change the variable from false to true.

Here is the code I'm working on for the nav:

```
   <li>
       <a  ng-click="toggleTheme(blackWhite)">  Black and White theme</a>
   </li>
```

and here is the code in the controller.

```
 $scope.blackWhite = false;
 //other themes are false
 $scope.toggleTheme = function(theme){
 theme = !theme;
 console.log($scope.blackWhite);//its still false
 }
```

How do I do this? Thanks

Comment: javascript doesn't have pass by reference.

Comment: You're never changing `$scope.blackWhite` so why would it not be false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work just fine if you pass a string to reference it instead:

```
<li>
  <a ng-click="toggleTheme('blackWhite')">Black and White theme</a>
</li>
```

Controller

```
$scope.blackWhite = false;

$scope.toggleTheme = function(theme){
  $scope[theme] = !$scope[theme];
}
```

You don't need to set the `blackWhite` or any other variable directly in your function. It's best to decouple as much as possible, which is where you were going with it originally :)

Comment: Great solution, I was just looking at the surface level problem in my answer (which would be tedious to implement and maintain for multiple themes).

Answer (score 4):

You're actually passing the value of $scope.blackWhite into that function, not a reference to $scope.blackWhite.  So you need to update the $scope variable with the new value, like this:

```
$scope.toggleTheme = function(theme) {
    $scope.blackWhite = !theme;
}
```

Or, better yet, don't pass a variable at all, since you're just toggling a boolean value:

```
$scope.toggleTheme = function() {
    $scope.blackWhite = !$scope.blackWhite;
}
```

Then your markup would be:

```
<a ng-click="toggleTheme()">Black and White theme</a>
```